# Formatting mouse over labels in plotly when using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am struggling with text formatting when using `ggplotly` and the mouse over functionality.

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(a=letters, b=LETTERS, x=runif(26), y=runif(26))
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(text=sprintf('letter: %s\nLetter: %s', a, b)))
g
(gg <- ggplotly(g))
```

I would like to have some formatted text or at least a newline in my mouse over label. Is there a good documentation on how to design this mouse over bubble thing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`plotly` can make use of the line break HTML tag.  You can get what your after using the `<br>` tag for a newline:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
       geom_point(aes(text=sprintf("letter: %s<br>Letter: %s", a, b)))

(gg <- ggplotly(g))
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't thought about that... This makes *even* so much more fun possible!!!

Comment: @drmariod this gives me an following error:
`Error: (converted from warning) Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text` ggplot2 is in version 2.2.1

Comment: Using this method in a line chart with multiple lines (differentiated by colour), I had to specifically add an aesthetic for group.  i.e. geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, text="", color=z, group=z)) without text the group=z is not necessary.  I then used ggplotly(p, tooltip="text") as per answer by @Jon Olav Vik.

Comment: For my case I also needed geom_line() variation. Code below worked:

myPlot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = a, text = b)) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, text = ""))
ggplotly(myPlot , tooltip="text")

Answer (score 77):

See the [`tooltip` argument to ggplotly()](https://rdrr.io/cran/plotly/man/ggplotly.html). For instance, to show only the species name (e.g. `virginica` for the top right point) on hover:

```
g <- ggplot(tail(iris), aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, text=Species)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(g, tooltip="text")
```

Other examples:

```
ggplotly(g, tooltip="x")             # Petal.Length: 5.7
ggplotly(g, tooltip="Petal.Length")  # Petal.Length: 5.7
ggplotly(g, tooltip=c("x", "y"))
```

The last example will show the two-line tooltip

```
Petal.Length: 5.7
Sepal.Length: 6.7
```

Comment: Tooltip for the win.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. That answer helped to fix my issue. Have a nice day.

Comment: is it possible to do this for variables that are not included in the original plot? To hover over a data point and see some/all other variables for that point?

Comment: @AndrewMcCartney That would be Species in my first example. The "text" aesthetic does not really exist and is not used by geom_point().

Comment: @JonOlavVik thank you super helpful. What if you want to add to the "text" aesthetic without overwriting it all-together?

Comment: @Ricky "text" is not really an aesthetic; perhaps you're thinking about "label"? You can use the label aesthetic yet have tooltips: ggplotly(ggplot(tail(iris), aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, label=Species, text=Sepal.Length)) + geom_text(), tooltip="text")

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [purrr's map function](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).  It kinda surprised me that it worked but I like it.

I bolded the 'letter:' and 'Letter:' headings. This still prints the x-y coordinates, which you can remove with the argument `tooltip` in `ggplotly()`.

```
df <- data.frame(a=letters, b=LETTERS, x=runif(26), y=runif(26))
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
         geom_point(aes(text=map(paste('<b>letter:</b>', a, '<br>', '<b>Letter:</b>', b), HTML)))
g
(gg <- ggplotly(g))
```