# mouse hover tool tips for geom_point formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605919/formatting-mouse-over-labels-in-plotly-when-using-ggplotly) answers states that formatting tool tip (which is shown when mouse is hovered over scatter plot in plotly) can be done via `text` aesthetic of `geom_point` BUT in my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605672/error-converted-from-warning-ignoring-unknown-aesthetics?noredirect=1#comment80163771_46605672) I was told that `text` should not be used as aesthetic for `geom_point` (it is working but sometimes it causes problems please refer to my second [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605672/error-converted-from-warning-ignoring-unknown-aesthetics?noredirect=1#comment80163771_46605672)). So where is the truth? My goal is to create tool tips which I can format (set specific parameters as stated in first mentioned [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605919/formatting-mouse-over-labels-in-plotly-when-using-ggplotly)) for `geom_point`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the aesthetic mapping under `ggplot` instead of `geom_point` to avoid the warning:

```
## This produces an "unknown aesthetic" warning
ggplot( mtcars, aes( x = wt, y = mpg ) ) + geom_point( aes( text = cyl ) )

## This doesn't
ggplot( mtcars, aes( x = wt, y = mpg, text = cyl ) ) + geom_point()
```

Also, consider using `key` aesthetic in place of `text` when adding simple information. The former preserves the column label.

When doing `aes( ..., text = cyl )`, the mouse-over label will look like this:

```
# wt: 2.620
# mpg: 21.0
# 6
```

When doing `aes( ..., key = cyl )`, the mouse-over label will look like this:

```
# wt: 2.620
# mpg: 21.0
# cyl: 6
```